# Amplify CUSTOM_AUTH login issue on iOS swift

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, custom-authentication

I am new to Amplify and want to integrate it with iOS swift. I followed [amplify_doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/existing-resources/q/platform/ios/)
to and created `amplifyconfiguration.json` and added it to the project. Configured with credentials provided such as PoolId, Region, AppClientId and web domain. Set authentication flow type as `"authenticationFlowType": "CUSTOM_AUTH"`.

I tried with simple sign-in API with username as:

```
Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: userName) { result in
   switch result {
   case .success:
      print("Sign in succeeded")
   case .failure(let error):
      print("Sign in failed \(error)")
      if let err = error.underlyingError as NSError? {
          print("Cast to nserror:", err)
      }
   }
```

Error: `Sign in failed AuthError: Incorrect username or password`.
This was password less authentication which works on Android but facing issues on iOS.

Also tried with `Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: <username>, password: nil)` still no success.
When nothing worked I tried with signUp API it worked and I received OTP on email successfully. The issue seems to be in the sign-in API.

---

Had a discussion on this bug with amplify team. For detailed response you can check [Amplify Issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift/issues/2028)

Comment: Looks like you've already found [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues/1783), but here's a link for anyone who finds this in the future.

Comment: I am also having the same issue and stuck for days

Answer (score 1):

First, you will have to signup the user, then sign in.

```
let attribute = [AuthUserAttribute(.phoneNumber, value: username)]
        let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(pluginOptions: attribute)
        Amplify.Auth.signUp(username: username, password: password, options: options) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                onCompletion(data,nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                onCompletion(nil,error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply but user is already created. Issue is present with Amplify Library.